# concat columns in perl

Tags: perl, merge, concatenation

Each iteration in my perl code generates a vector of 5.
Output of first iteration is

```
out1
1
2
3
4
5
```

The second iterations generates same length of vector.

```
out2
10
20
30
40
50
```

and then it runs for nth time

```
out n
100
200
300
400
500
```

I want to merge these columns and have the final output in a tabular format or matrix format if you like:

```
out1 out2 ... outn
1    10       100
2    20       200
3    30       300
4    40       400
5    50       500
```

I tried splitting and then using the push but it prints "(101" and only do it once and not for all 20. I also have no idea where the "(101" comes from.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please also include your problematic code in your question.

Comment: Show the code and we can show you how to fix it. Otherwise, you need to say how your vectors are stored, and how they are output.

Answer (score 0):

First, put all those output lists to a list. Second, iterate on that list: output every first element of each element-list in the first iteration, output every second element of each element-list in the second iteration, and so on.

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @lists;

for my $i (1..10) {
    my @list;
    push @list, $_ * $i for (1..5);

    push @lists, \@list;
}

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
print Dumper(\@lists), "\n\n";

while (@{$lists[0]}) {
    for my $list (@lists) {
        print shift @$list, "\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

---

Output:

```
$ perl t.pl 
$VAR1 = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [2,4,6,8,10],
  [3,6,9,12,15],
  [4,8,12,16,20],
  [5,10,15,20,25],
  [6,12,18,24,30],
  [7,14,21,28,35],
  [8,16,24,32,40],
  [9,18,27,36,45],
  [10,20,30,40,50]
];

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
```

---

Note: The output of `Data::Dumper` has been edited to make it more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Save your vector information to an array of array as you do your processing.  Then you can output the rows using a simple join:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @rows;

for my $i (1..10) {
    my @vector = map {$i * $_} (1..5);

    push @{$rows[$_]}, $vector[$_] for (0..$#vector);
}

for my $row (@rows) {
    print join(" ", map {sprintf "%-3s", $_} @$row), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
```

Note: It'd be a lot easier to advise if you provided code and actual data.